# How to convert contents of csv to lowercase in Python?

Tags: python, csv, lowercase

I've looked at all the threads I can find but I still can't figure it out, I'm having all sorts of issues.

First issue is that I can't change the items in a list to lower case, so I have to convert it to a string first.  Once I do that I can't append strings back into the list without it creating a double list.  Why can't I simply change a list to lowercase, delete contents in csv, then paste the lowercase list back in?

My latest attempt, but I've tried many things.

```
with open(teacherDD, 'r+') as f:
read = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in read:
    copyRow = row.copy()
    # print(copyRow)
    del row[:]
    # print(row)
    getLowerStr = str(copyRow).lower()
    # appendLower = row.append(getLowerStr)
    # print(getLowerStr)
    print(row)
    f.write(getLowerStr)
f.close()
```

Comment: Posted my latest attempt

Comment: Please explain why you cannot convert the items of a list to lowercase. Doesn't `l = [str(x).lower() for x in l]` work for you?

Comment: That seems to create a list inside of a list

Comment: It shouldn't... `x` might *contain* brackets, but that is one list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to convert to lowercase, why use the csv reader?

You can use the `fileinput` module to edit lines in place.

#### Python3.x

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("test.txt", inplace=1):
    print(line.lower(), end='')
```

#### Python2.x

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input("test.txt", inplace=1):
    sys.stdout.write(line.lower())
```

One cool feature of this module is, when you open a file with it, anything that is printed with `print` or `sys.stdout.write` is redirected to the file.
Sample input:

```
UPPER,CASE,ROW
```

Output:

```
upper,case,row
```

Comment: I didn't know of that module.  This solves the problem.